# Android - PageViewer View stuck on screen

Tags: android, view, fragment, swipe, viewer

i'm trying to get this pageviewer with fragments to work however i'm stumbled on a problem where the view stays on screen on swipe. Ideally, i'd want it to only be on a particular layout yet i'm not too sure why it "carries over" to other screens (it also stays on screen during the transition between fragments).

Any feedback will be appreciated!

[Link to Imgur Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USVsj.jpg)

Main:

```
private void initUI()
{
    // ---------Page Viewer with Fragments -----------

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }


    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

---

Adapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Main Frag
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            // Second Frag
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            // Third Frag
            return new Fragment3();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

---

Fragment classes are basically this:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EditText is in the main layout, the same layout that the ViewPager is in. It should be inflated within the tab. You'll need to create a separate layout for each tab.

Main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need to inflate the new layout in fragment 1.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_1, container, false);

return rootView;
```

Comment: Ahh you're 100% correct. Thanks for the quick and straight to the point reply.